# From a running EC2 instance, how do I download the AWS generated private key for use with SSH and WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp

From a running EC2 instance, how do I download the AWS generated private key for use with SSH and WinSCP in PEM format?

[image]

I expected to see Download on the Actions menu, but it's not there.  I'm posting this after spending a few hours trying to get this information in a way I can understand it.

Comment: **You must download the private key during the creation operation.** Once that's complete it's no longer possible. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-key-pairs.html step 9 in the first section (create on EC2)

Comment: If you didn't download the key during creation, you could create an AMI from your instance and create another instance with another key.